# Typescript doesn't allow typeof inheritance of classes with different constructor signatures

Tags: inheritance, static, compiler-errors, typescript

I am implementing a commandBus, and I want to register command types with command handlers to map incoming commands to the right command handler. I passed a command constructor to map to a handler constructor like so `register(handler : typeof Handler, command : typeof Command)`. But I kept getting compilaton errors.

I finally isolated the reason. In typescript, you can't define an argument `arg typeof X` and pass in a constructor `Y`, event if '`Y extends X`. **The constructors must have the same signature**.

Check that snippet. At the bottom, even `commandBus.register(Object)` does not throw compilation errors.

```
class BaseClass{}
class DerivedClass extends BaseClass{
    constructor(b : number) {
        super();
    }
}
class AnotherClass extends BaseClass{
    constructor(){
        super();
    }
}
class CommandBus {
    register(handler : typeof BaseClass) {}
}
var commandBus = new CommandBus();
commandBus.register(DerivedClass); // Argument of type 'typeof DerivedClass' is not assignable to parameter of type 'typeof BaseClass'.
commandBus.register(AnotherClass); // Compiles
commandBus.register(Function); // Compiles
commandBus.register(Object); // Compiles
```

The only way I got this to work is to add an overload constructor signature

```
class DerivedClass extends BaseClass{
    constructor(b? : any);
    constructor(b : number) {
        super();
    }
}
```

But is it me or this is damn ugly?

Can anyone point me into a direction on how to get rid of these compiler errors without a dirty hack of adding useless overload signature all over the place?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you're really trying to say here is that you want a constructor function for a `BaseClass` that takes any number of arguments. You can write that type:

```
class CommandBus {
    register(handler: new(...args: any[]) => BaseClass) {}
}
```

---

Note that the error is 100% correct. If you had written

```
class CommandBus {
    register(handler : typeof BaseClass) {
       var x = new handler();
    }
}
var c = new CommandBus();
c.register(DerivedClass);
```

You'd be passing zero arguments to the `DerivedClass` constructor.

---

These lines down here

```
commandBus.register(Function); // Compiles
commandBus.register(Object); // Compiles
```

only compile because `BaseClass` has no members (remember, TypeScript uses a structural type system, so the empty type is assignable *from* any type!). If you add any properties or methods to `BaseClass` that aren't in `Function` or `Object`, these lines become errors.

Comment: Thank you very much, that did it!

Comment: But why is it possible to use `register(handler : BaseClass)` and use `register(derivedClassInstance)` and not use `register(handler : typeof BaseClass)` with `register(DerivedClass)` ? Shouldn't Typescript allow this kind of usage? I don't know typescript in depth, but intuitively isn't this logical? Maybe it's because I'm used to be able to pass in a class in other OO languages (Java, Pascal).

Comment: It's about substitutability -- `typeof DerivedClass` isn't actually substitutable for `typeof BaseClass` because it requires additional constructor arguments. By the same rule, you *could* get an error with `register(derivedClassInstance)` if your derived class instance shape wasn't assignable to the base class instance type.

Comment: this won't work if base class is abstract